# OpenLDAP RHEL 6

Tags: redhat, ldap

I've been configuring OpenLDAP on RHEL 6 and its seems you have run the following to rebuild the config dirs. I'm ok with that , but my issues is , say I want to change the server passwd , do I have to go through the whole process every time I change the config ? Is there a way of changing the slapd config after its been built using the RHEL6 method ?

below is the advice I've found on the net from http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel6/rhel_6_migration_guide/rhel_6_migration_ch07s03.html

> This example assumes that the file to
>   convert from the old slapd
>   configuration is located at
>   /etc/openldap/slapd.conf and the new
>   directory for OpenLDAP configuration
>   is located at /etc/openldap/slapd.d/.
>   Remove the contents of the new
>   /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ directory:
>
> rm -rf /etc/openldap/slapd.d/*
>
> Run slaptest to check the validity of
>   the configuration file and specify the
>   new configuration directory:  slaptest
>   -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d
>
> Configure permissions on the new
>   directory:  chown -R ldap:ldap
>   /etc/openldap/slapd.d
>
> chmod -R 000 /etc/openldap/slapd.d
>
> chmod -R u+rwX /etc/openldap/slapd.d

To clarify. I'm after help on how to edit the slapd configuration using the newer versions of openldap , where the config is held in a schema rather than the original slapd.conf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guys over at UNIX/Linux stack gave me a good answer.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16092/doing-openldap-config-changes-in-rhel-6

Comment: Why accept your own answer saying you found no solution. Edit or post answer hoping people will help you now that your question is up again.

Comment: Ok I've found the answer , can I have the downvotes removed ?

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions are for when you are converting from an old-style `slapd.conf` configuration file to a new-style `slapd.d/*` configuration directory. You only have to do this when moving your configuration. Once.

Comment: Even if he add to do again the whole process, creating a script to doing it is quite easy. :)

Comment: I was after intructions on how to do configuration changes on the new style config. Impatient ? it was around 4 months ago :-)

Comment: Anarko , adding a comment on your comment is quite easy also :) but not very helpfull regarding the orginal problem.

Comment: Sorry about that.